# Problem with run node prune in docker file

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I follow to this [reference](https://itsopensource.com/how-to-reduce-node-docker-image-size-by-ten-times/) to reduce my docker image. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10 as builder
RUN curl -sfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/tj/node-prune.sh | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production
RUN /usr/local/bin/node-prune
FROM node:10-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /app/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start:dev
```

However when run docker build I got the error. Thank for your attention.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just include the text in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: It looks like `node-prune` isn't installed in `/usr/local/bin`. Have you inspected that directory? You could stick a `RUN ls ...` in your Dockerfile, for example.

Comment: Since you're just running the dev server, what's the point in trying to prune dependencies?

Comment: @Phil, I just want to reduce the capacity of image docker, it's quite heavy

Comment: @larsks, when I add RUN ls, nothing happend

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Running a clean `node:10` image, I can run `npm init -y && npm prune --production` without any issue. I certainly didn't have to manually install `node-prune`. Have you tried removing that step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below lines:

```
RUN curl -sf https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune | sh

RUN node-prune /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: @Tyler2P Yes. the first command will help us to get the shell script to download and install the node-prune on the /usr/local/bin. The second command helps to run the node-prune on the specific directory where you like to remove the unwanted files.

Answer (score 1):

The curl command uses `-s` (`--silent`) which is suppressing a failure to get the install script since that URL is dead and [node-prune no longer uses goreleaser](https://github.com/tj/node-prune/issues/67).

Adding the curl `-S` (`--show-error`) option will ensure errors are raised:

```
$ curl -sSfL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/tj/node-prune.sh | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: install.goreleaser.com
```

#### Install

Official node-prune [install instructions](https://github.com/tj/node-prune#installation) use `gobinaries.com`:

```
RUN curl -sSf https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune | sh
```

Alternatively since curl is not in base Docker Alpine images you can use `wget`:

```
wget -O - https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune | sh
```

The default install location is `/usr/local/bin` but can use `PREFIX` var to change that:

```
curl -sSf https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune | PREFIX=/tmp/ sh
```